# Count the new element added and removed from the previous group from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am having a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Quarter" = c("Q1 2019","Q1 2019","Q1 2019","Q2 2019","Q2 2019","Q2 2019","Q2 2019","Q3 2019","Q3 2019","Q3 2019","Q3 2019","Q4 2019","Q4 2019"),
  "Name" = c("Ram","John","Jack","Ram","Rach","Will","John","Ram","Rach","Will","John","Rach","John"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I need to calculate the number of persons who were added and left in each quarter by comparing it with the previous quarter.

The expected output is

```
quarterYear status Count
1    Q1 2019 Added   3
2    Q1 2019 Left    0
3    Q2 2019 Added   2
4    Q2 2019 Left    1
5    Q3 2019 Added   0
6    Q3 2019 Left    0
7    Q4 2019 Added   0
8    Q4 2019 Left    2
```

I am not sure of how to compare two groups and get the count.

How can I achieve the expected output in R?

Comment: Why does Q1 have 4 added?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about the speed implications, but a big part of this is essentially comparing consecutive counts, so `diff` came to mind.

```
tab <- table(df$Quarter, df$Name)
tab <- rbind(tab[1,,drop=FALSE], diff(tab))
out <- rbind(added = rowSums(tab == 1), left = rowSums(tab == -1))

#      Q1 2019 Q2 2019 Q3 2019 Q4 2019
#added       3       2       0       0
#left        0       1       0       2
```

If you need the long output specifically:

```
setNames(data.frame(as.table(out)), c("status","quarter","count"))
#  status quarter count
#1  added Q1 2019     3
#2   left Q1 2019     0
#3  added Q2 2019     2
#4   left Q2 2019     1
#5  added Q3 2019     0
#6   left Q3 2019     0
#7  added Q4 2019     0
#8   left Q4 2019     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Split to create a list and map the two lists to get the length of the 'unequal' elements, i.e.

```
l1 <- split(df$Name, df$Quarter)
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) { i1 <- length(setdiff(x, y)); 
                                    i2 <- length(setdiff(y, x)); 
                                    data.frame(Added = i1, Left = i2)},
          l1[-1], l1[-length(l1)]))

#        Added Left
#Q2 2019     2    1
#Q3 2019     0    0
#Q4 2019     0    2
```

You can tidy the output the way you want

Answer (score 1):

The following works by first turning the `Name` column into a list of names by `Quarter`, and then comparing every Quarter with the previous Quarter using `purrr::map2_int`.
Finally, the two columns that were added, `Added` and `Left` are pivoted into long form using `tidyr::pivot_longer`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Quarter) %>%
  summarise(names = list(Name)) %>%
  mutate(Added = map2_int(names, lag(names, default = list(list())), ~ length(setdiff(.x, .y))),
         Left = map2_int(names, lag(names, default = list(list())), ~ length(setdiff(.y, .x)))) %>%
  pivot_longer(Added:Left, names_to = "status", values_to = "Count") %>%
  select(-names)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Quarter status Count
  <chr>   <chr>  <int>
1 Q1 2019 Added      3
2 Q1 2019 Left       0
3 Q2 2019 Added      2
4 Q2 2019 Left       1
5 Q3 2019 Added      0
6 Q3 2019 Left       0
7 Q4 2019 Added      0
8 Q4 2019 Left       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way keeping the data wide. We split the data into list of dataframes based on `Quarter`. Using `map2` we compare one quarter and the next quarter values and count number of people added and left in each quarter. Calculate the values for first quarter separately and bind it to the original dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)

list_df <- df %>% group_split(Quarter)

list_df %>%
   .[[1]] %>%
  summarise(quarterYear  = first(Quarter),
            status = c('Added', 'Left'), 
            Count = c(n(), 0)) %>%
    bind_rows(map2_df(list_df[-1], list_df[-length(list_df)], 
            ~tibble(quarterYear = .x$Quarter[1],
                    status = c('Added', 'Left'), 
                    Count = c(sum(!.x$Name %in% .y$Name), 
                              sum(!.y$Name %in% .x$Name)))))


# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  quarterYear status Count
#  <chr>       <chr>  <dbl>
#1 Q1 2019     Added      3
#2 Q1 2019     Left       0
#3 Q2 2019     Added      2
#4 Q2 2019     Left       1
#5 Q3 2019     Added      0
#6 Q3 2019     Left       0
#7 Q4 2019     Added      0
#8 Q4 2019     Left       2
```

---

Using the same logic in base R:

```
list_df <- split(df, df$Quarter)
temp <- list_df[[1]]

rbind(data.frame(quarterYear = temp$Quarter[1], 
                 status =  c('Added', 'Left'), 
                 Count = c(nrow(temp), 0)),
   do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) 
      data.frame(quarterYear = x$Quarter[1],
                 status = c('Added', 'Left'), 
                 Count = c(sum(!x$Name %in% y$Name), sum(!y$Name %in% x$Name))), 
list_df[-1],list_df[-length(list_df)])))
```